# How to flush left single alignat environments

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath, alignat

Im looking for a way to "flush left" single `alignat`-environments, like in the `flalign`-environment. This, however doesn't suit my needs, as I want to align equation marks of different lines and have other, left-aligned lines, which are possibly longer and left-aligned using `\mathrlap`. Using `flalign` naturally shifts the equation marks to the right. (`fleqn` is no option, as most equations in the document should be centered.)

```
\documentclass[varwidth=10cm, border=2pt
,convert={ghostscript, density={500}}
]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}

\newcommand{\mathphantlong}{
    a x^2 + bx^2 + cx^4 + dx^5 + ex^6 + fx^7 + \ldots
}
\newcommand{\mathphantshorta}{
    bu + cu^2
}
\newcommand{\mathphantshortb}{
    d y + e\sqrt{y}
}
\begin{document}
It should look like this:
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{alignat}{2}
            & \mathrlap{\underline{i = j:}}\nonumber\\[0.1cm]
            & \mathrlap{\mathphantlong} \\
            &&[\mathphantshorta &= \mathphantshortb]_{i \leq m}\\
            &\mathrlap{[ \mathphantlong}\nonumber\\
            &&& = \mathphantshortb]_{i > m}
        \end{alignat}
    \end{subequations}
But left aligned like in:
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{flalign}
            & \mathrlap{\underline{i = j:}}\nonumber\\[0.1cm]
            & \mathrlap{\mathphantlong} \\
            &&[\mathphantshorta &= \mathphantshortb]_{i \leq m}\\
            &\mathrlap{[ \mathphantlong}\nonumber\\
            &&& = \mathphantshortb]_{i > m}
        \end{flalign}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: note the fl in `flalign` is not for "flush left" but "full length", we have answers somewhere for switching between fleqn  and centred settings mid-document,  I'll search..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the hint "full length". Still the problem remains the same. I found a few things about that but none fit my needs :(

Comment: it's very hard to suggest any answer as it isn't clear why you want to use `align...` there is no alignment here all there terms are in mathrlap so  there alignment even possible as the size of the terms is hidden, it would seem gather or multline would be far more suitable

Comment: The = shall be aligned. There can more lines and using phantom is not as easy as it is in the MWE